# HTML5 Canvas and light source

Tags: html, canvas

The HTML5 canvas has the gradients and shadow elements to add shadowing effects. However, it seems that having a light source mentioned would have the shadow effects be more realistic. Is there any such method to mention a light source or is one being planned ?

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can use scripts such as Three.js that provides suchs features.

Comment: Three.js example: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_lights_pointlights.html

Answer (score 0):

No, the canvas API does not include any built in "lighting" features.